# React Native Music Database MP3

Tags: reactjs, react-native, expo

Hi everyone I'm in need of some help here with React Native &/or Expo.

**The brief version:** I built the UI for a streaming app idea of mine. My problem now is finding a way to add content on it!

**How can I add music files or MP3 & Videos on React Native (preferably Expo)?
Is there such free database out there or would I have to build something to pass the data to the app itself?**

**The long version:** I had an idea to build a Hybrid Streaming App  including music, videos and live events. Now this is my first time building an app ever. I managed to get the UI done in 4 months.

Again I've never done this before so don't crucify me. I managed to use flatlist to create categories which represent: music, videos, podcast, and live events. In those flatlist I passed data which are the artist, image, album & more. I even was able to create a player screen and actually play some random audio file using "Expo-av" using a link. Right now, I'm stuck and still trying to find a way to get an actual library on the app while also figuring out how to pass data from one thing to the next. PLEASE HELP

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if there's a good white-label service that would provide metadata and streaming audio/video. Something like [MusicBrainz](https://musicbrainz.org) offers an [API](https://musicbrainz.org/doc/MusicBrainz_API) for metadata, but I don't think they provide audio. There may be companies out there that offer what you're looking for, as I understand it, but licensing for major label music is notoriously thorny, so there may not be a ton of companies that give you drop-in access to something like Spotify's library. If you want people to upload media, you can use something like [AWS Amplify](https://sandbox.amplifyapp.com/getting-started) to integrate a backend without having to do a lot of devops work.

Comment: Awesome! I’m going to look into AWS Amplify right away.